# Component alignment java

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, alignment, box

I am learning GUI in java and I'm having a problem with component allignment.
I am using a vertical Box that has 3 horizontal boxes.
I want the fist and the third box to allign in the center and the second to allign left. 
Here is the code.

```
   public class KopjoFushen extends JFrame
   {
    private JTextField text;
    private JTextField text2;
    public KopjoFushen()

    {
    super("Kopjo fushen");

    JLabel label=new JLabel();
    label.setText("Fusha1");
    text =new JTextField(10);
    Box siper=Box.createHorizontalBox();
    siper.add(label);
    siper.add(text);
    text2 =new JTextField(60);
    text2.setEditable(false);
    text2.setText("Fusha e pandryshueshme");
    Box mes=Box.createHorizontalBox();
    mes.add(text2);
    JButton buton=new JButton("Kopjo fushen e lire");
    buton.addActionListener(new ButonHandler());
    Box poshte=Box.createHorizontalBox();
    poshte.add(buton);
    Box total=Box.createVerticalBox();
    total.add(siper);
    siper.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
    mes.setAlignmentX(Component.RIGHT_ALIGNMENT);
    total.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
    total.add(mes);
    total.add(poshte);
    setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    add(total);
  }
```

The first problem is that both the first Boxes allign left.
The second problem is that if I use a bigger number in the constructor of the second JTextField the first JTextField gets bigger.
Here is what I want to achieve
http://prntscr.com/e8utum
and here is what i have done: http://prntscr.com/e8uusn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first Box is actually centered. It seems to be aligned to the left because it is resized to fit the parent panel.

In fact if you set the JTextField maximumSize you will notice that it is centered

```
 text.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(300, Integer.MAX_VALUE));
```

Comment: that seems to do it. Thank you